# how to clear httprequest from webdriver Remote hub to rc

Tags: webdriver

i have a webdriver remote Hub Rc execution scenario. Once i started the execution, requests get queued up in the hub waiting for free instances. But when i killed the execution, the requests it seems remain in the console. As a result, blank pages gets opened in my RCs.

Is there a way to clear the pending http requests from Hub cache once execution stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working perfectly

First set .value of each httprequest dom element.

```
xhr[i].value = i;
```

then output it inside the progress event like this:

```
console.log(this.value + " : " + percentCompleteRounded);
```